# ¿Por qué no se pasa el valor de mi variable a la otra forma en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, objeto

**Hola a todos, les cuento...**
Lo que quiero hacer es pasar simplemente el valor que tengo en la variable lblNivel a otra forma como se puede apreciar en la línea 96 pero no se pasa y no se porque.En si, Visual no lo marca como error porque según la maquina si se pasa pero al final resulta que tiene un valor null.

Puse el punto para ver como se pasaban los valores y llegue a la conclución de que según si se pasa el valor de la variable lblNivel a la otra forma pero cuando lo intento usar me dice que es null.

Adjunto unas imagenes para que entiendan de que hablo:
**Pongan atención en la consola**

[image: En esta imagen se puede apreciar abajo que la variable Nivel de la forma Desafios si toma el valor de 10]

[image: Y aquí me muestra la variable Nivel como NULL]

***Gracias de antemano***

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Este tipo de problemas suelen venir de estar asignando el valor a una instancia del formulario, y sin embargo estar mostrando otra. En la captura veo que asignas el valor a `desafios` pero no veo que muestres el formulario, asi que deduzco que el problema es el que te he descrito

Comment: pega tu codigo aca.

Answer (score 0):

Donde haces el desafios.Show()??
Quizás estas tratando de acceder a desafíos desde una instancia distinta a la que creas en el otro formulario.

Lo otro en el formulario de nivel donde tienes los if para la asignación de lblNivel basta con que asignes de la siguiente manera:
    lblNivel.Text=nivel;

Answer (score 0):

Deberías crear un constructor sobrecargado para pasar ese valor y dejar el constructor por defecto por si lo llegaras a necesitar, si no es así solo dejas el constructor con parámetros para poder pasar el valor que necesites.
Luego veo que verificas con un `if` si el valor es igual a 10, para darle ese valor a tu `Label`, eso no tienen ningún sentido, simplemente le pasas el valor a tu `Label`

```
public partial class FrmDesafios : Form
{
    public FrmDesafios()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public FrmDesafios(string valor)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblNivel.Text = valor;
    }
}
```

En tu formulario `Form1`, que le pasas el valor, seria de esta forma.

```
FrmDesafio f = new FrmDesafio(lblNivel.Text);
f.Show();
```